# Reproducing 3-D Visual Diagram of a function dependent on 3 variables drawn with Mathematica using Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, 3d

Hello I am trying to produce a working code on MATLAB for a visual 3-D diagram of

[3-D Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW1LJ.png)

[3-D Diagram Produced in Mathematica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fZoe.jpg)

The code I ran to draw the figure on Mathematica is

```
F[x_, k_, r_] := x^4 + k x^2 + r*x
ContourPlot3D[
Evaluate[D[F[x, k, r], x]], {k, -2.5, 2}, {r, -2.2, 3}, {x, -1.4, 
1.3}, PlotPoints -> 7, ViewPoint -> {-1.5, 1.5, 1.4}, Axes -> True,
ContourStyle -> {EdgeForm[]}, 
AxesLabel -> TraditionalForm /@ {k, r, x}] // Timing
```

I'm currently trying to produce a similar 3-D diagram but with MATLAB. Currently I have a working code that produces a 3-D visual of a simple spherical function dependent on 3 variables using the MATLAB code

```
a = 10;
x = linspace(-a,a);
y = linspace(-a,a);
z = linspace(-a,a);
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);
f = x.^2 + y.^2 + z.^2;
k = 100;
p = patch(isosurface(x,y,z,f,k));
isonormals(x,y,z,f,p)
p.FaceColor = 'blue';
p.EdgeColor = 'none';
title(sprintf('Contours of f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2\nwith        f(x,y,z) = k = %d',k));
xlabel('x-axis');
ylabel('y-axis');
zlabel('z-axis');
axis equal;
grid on;
box on;
axis([-10 10 -10 10 -10 10]);
camlight left;
lighting phong;
```

[3-D MATLAB Sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BNi3.png)

When I try to replace the function used to generate the spherical code with the same derivative of the function used in my Mathematica code the program will not run. Specifically, if I defined 
f = 4x.^3 + 2*y*x + z 
the program does not run, which I believe is due to the fact the function is dependent on a non independent product y*z. I want to know how I can modify my code to produce a figure similar to the one I originally or any suggestions on which MATLAB functions I need to look into to draw a 3-D diagram of a function dependent on 3 variables. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `4x.^3 + 2*y*x + z` -> `4x.^3 + 2*y.*x + z` for elementwise multiplication in the middle. I presume "program does not run" means "there's an error". If you do it right you get a surface, albeit a pretty boring one (it's flat). I suspect you need to tweak your parameters to get an interesting surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `DF = 4*x.^3 + 2*k.*x + r;` as gradient of `F`. Here `.^` and `.*` are used for elementwise power and multiplication since `x`, `k`, and `r` are matrices.

```
x = linspace(-1.4, 1.3);
k = linspace(-2.5, 2);
r = linspace(-2.2, 3);
[x,k,r] = meshgrid(x,k,r);
DF = 4*x.^3 + 2*k.*x + r;
v = 0.1;
p = patch(isosurface(x,k,r,DF,v));
isonormals(x,k,r,DF,p)
p.FaceColor = 'blue';
p.EdgeColor = 'none';
title(sprintf('Contours of DF(x,k,r) = 4x^3 + 2kx + r\nwith        DF(x,k,r) = v = %d',v));
xlabel('x-axis');
ylabel('y-axis');
zlabel('z-axis');
axis equal;
axis square;
grid on;
box on;
axis([-1.4 1.3 -2.5 2 -2.2 3]);
camlight left;
lighting phong;
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I would add `axis square` for nicer visual effect ;)

Comment: @AnderBiguri It has been added :)